# Registering A record in DNS remotely using powershell

Tags: powershell, dns

Below is my script, Please let me know if am missing something.

```
#Script to add DNS 'A' Records 'PTR' Records to DNS Servers
$dns = "afidc1.XXXXXXX.com" # Your DNS Server Name
$Zone = "XXXXXXX.com" # Your Forward Lookup Zone Name
$IP = "X.X.X.X" 
$Name = "pweb17s1"
$localuser = "XXXXXX\mayigi01"
$localpass = "XXXXXX"
Enter-PSSession –ComputerName $dns -GuestCredential $localuser $localpass
Import-Module DnsServer
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA –ComputerName $dns -Name $Name -IPv4Address $IP -ZoneName $Zone
```

Below is the error am facing:

```
Enter-PSSession : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'â€ComputerName 'afidc1.XXXXX.com'
-GuestCredential XXXXX\mayigi01 XXXXX
Import-Module DnsServer
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA â€ComputerName'.
At C:\Users\devoops!\Desktop\dns.ps1:9 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession â€“ComputerName 'afidc1.XXXXX.com' -GuestCredential $localus ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enter-PSSession], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand
```

Comment: Replace the – in front of ComputerName with -

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it dint work! i am getting same error after replacing

Comment: Am editing my script with Notepad++ V6.9.2

Answer (score 2):

I used the ISE:

just copy it from here maybe?

```
#Script to add DNS 'A' Records 'PTR' Records to DNS Servers
$dns = "afidc1.XXXXXXX.com" # Your DNS Server Name
$Zone = "XXXXXXX.com" # Your Forward Lookup Zone Name
$IP = "X.X.X.X" 
$Name = "pweb17s1"
$localuser = "XXXXXX\mayigi01"
$localpass = "XXXXXX"
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $dns -GuestCredential $localuser $localpass
Import-Module DnsServer
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA –ComputerName $dns -Name $Name -IPv4Address $IP -ZoneName $Zone
```